# How distance affect wind speed from a fan?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, aerodynamics, distance, fan

I noticed that when you feel the wind force from a fan close up, it feels like more force than from far away. Can someone give me an equation, where given a base wind speed $v$ in mph of the fan, and a distance $d$ in miles, one can get the wind speed from distance d away from the fan.

Comment: I can't think of any fan whose flow force dropoff would be measured in miles.  More like feet, even for a jet engine

Comment: I feel it's not a trivial task, probably you would need to solve full or partial Navier-Stokes equations for this to determine.

Answer (score 1):

Check Landau & Lifshits, vol.6 ("Fluid Mechanics"), ch.23 ("Exact solutions of the equations of motion for a viscous fluid"), item (3) "submerged jet". I believe this is the closest thing for an analytical expression for your problem.